# Objective C: Properties Not Found In Forward Declaration Vs Parse Issue: Expected A Type

Tags: objective-c, forward-declaration

I have a singleton class called DataManager.  This class is used by several other classes to deal with loading and saving plist files.

I am adding the ability for DataManager to save screenshots as well as plist files. This requires me to load the view I wish to take a screenshot of.  The view I'm loading comes from a controller that imports DataManager.

Obviously this is circular dependency, so I used:

```
@class GardenView;
```

However, this resulted in the following errors:

- Receiver 'GardenView' for class message is a forward declaration
- Receiver type 'GardenView' for instance message is a forward
- declaration  Property 'bounds' cannot be found in forward class
- object 'GardenView'  Property 'layer' cannot be found in forward
  class object 'GardenView'

This seems like it can't find properties inherited from the UIView superclass.  Is this true of forward class declarations?

If I use the standard #import instead of @class, I get:

- Parse Issue: Expected A Type

for the methods in GardenView referencing Plant (which I am importing just fine):

```
- (void) addPlantToView: (Plant*) plant;
- (void) addPlantToGarden: (Plant*) plant;
- (void) addPlantToViewAndGarden: (Plant*) plant;
```

The Plant class DOES import the DataManager, but if I change it to @class, I get:

- No known class method for selector 'sharedDataManager'

What is the solution for this problem?  The class method is there in the header file (+sharedDataManager). Am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't made it clear where exactly you're doing the imports vs `@class`. And I think that's causing confusion. Here's what you want to do:

- In GardenView.h, use `@class Plant`
- In Plant.h, use `@class GardenView`
- In GardenView.m, use `#import "Plant.h"`
- In Plant.m, use `#import "GardenView.m"`

This breaks the circular dependency in the headers, but still allows the implementations to see the full information of the dependent class.

Now the reason why `@class` alone isn't sufficient is because all `@class Foo` does is it tells the compiler "There exists a class named Foo", without telling it anything at all about the class. The compiler doesn't know its methods. It doesn't know its superclass. All it knows is if it sees the token `Foo`, then that represents a class type. You can use this in header files so you can refer to the class in arguments and return types, but in order to actually do anything with values of that type you still need the full `#import`. But you can put that `#import` in the .m file without any problem.

The only time you need `#import` instead of `@class` in your header is if you want to inherit from the class in question. You cannot inherit from forward-declared classes, so you need the full `#import`. Of course, you may also need the `#import` if you need access to other types defined in the same header (e.g. structs, enums, etc.), but that's less common in obj-c.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I thought all import/@class declarations had to be in the header file, and that the only import that could be in the .m file was the reference to its own header. Thank you!

Comment: @Jenny: Nope. All an `#import` does is literally copy&paste the contents of the referenced file in place of the `#import` line (well, it also checks to see if the header has been imported before, and does nothing if it has. That's how it differs from `#include`). You can even put code in your .h if it's ok for the code to be included in multiple translation units (read: source files), although that's pretty rare.

Comment: "The only time you need #import instead of @class in your header is if you want to inherit from the class in question." Thanks, was not aware of this.

Comment: This indeed a great post.!!